# Similarity of $2X2$ matrix when it has exactly one eigenvalue.

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

I'm having a difficulty to determine if the following is true or false.

Let $A \in M_{nxn}(\mathbb{R}).$ If $n=2$ and $A$ has exactly one eigenvalue, then $A$ is similar to $\begin{pmatrix}\lambda &0\\ \:0&\lambda \:\end{pmatrix}$ *or* $\begin{pmatrix}\lambda &1\\ \:0&\lambda \:\end{pmatrix}$.

Is there a counter example?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form

Comment: If the above post is sufficient to provide an answer, please write one yourself so that you can close this question.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг will do once I'll be sure. Haven't had the chance yet to dive deep in that wiki link.

Comment: All right. You may call me once you are done, so that I can view your answer, and comment/upvote if necessary.